# c# identifier expected?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a program to copy all the files from one directory to another. But I am running in a basic issue. It says indentifier expected when I try to compile on line 52.

```
public bool RecursiveCopy()
{
    string origDir = @"D:\Documents and Settings\Dub\My Documents\HoN Updates\test";
    string destDir = @"C:\Games\HoN";
    bool status = false;

    //get all the info about the original directory
    var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(origDir);

    //retrieve all the _fileNames in the original directory
    var files = dirInfo.GetFiles(origDir);

    //always use a try...catch to deal 
    //with any exceptions that may occur
    try
    {
        //loop through all the file names and copy them
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(origDir))
        {
            var origFile = new FileInfo(file);
            var destFile = new FileInfo(file.Replace(origDir, destDir));

            //copy the file, use the OverWrite overload to overwrite
            //destination file if it exists

            System.IO.File.Copy(origFile.FullName, destFile.FullName, true);

            //TODO: If you dont want to remove the original
            //_fileNames comment this line out
            File.Delete(origFile.FullName);
            status = true;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("All files in " + origDir + " copied successfully!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        status = false;

        //handle any errors that may have occurred
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return status;
}

public string origDir = @"D:\Documents and Settings\Dub\My Documents\HoN Updates\test"; // ERROR HERE
public string destDir = @"C:\Games\HoN"; // ERROR HERE

private static void RecursiveCopy(origDir, destDir)
{
    Console.WriteLine("done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You did not give type identifiers to your argument list here

```
static void RecursiveCopy(origDir, destDir)
```

should be

```
static void RecursiveCopy(string origDir, string destDir)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your method `RecursiveCopy` has two parameters listed without their types. It should be this:

```
static void RecursiveCopy(string origDir, string destDir)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem:

```
static void RecursiveCopy(origDir, destDir)
```

You don't specify the types for the parameters, perhaps you intended the following:

```
static void RecursiveCopy(string origDir, string destDir)
```

---

There are more issues however that I've noticed. It's possible you're still working on these, but from what you've posted:

- You never call your `RecursiveCopy` method. Perhaps you meant to *call it from `Main()`* instead of declaring an overload with two parameters?
- You declare two public fields `origDir` and `destDir` but then never use them. Instead you create two local variables in `RecursiveCopy()` and use these instead. *Did you intend to create parameters or use the public fields instead?*
- Your copy is not actually true to its name of "recursive".

Comment: "Perhaps you meant to call it from Main() instead of declaring an overload with two parameters?"  - Seems like that is the intention, explains the missing type specifiers.

Answer (score 1):

cYou are missing the parameter types in the `RecursiveCopy` method declaration. Just Change

```
static void RecursiveCopy(origDir, destDir)
```

to

```
static void RecursiveCopy(String origDir, String destDir)
```

and all is fine.