# There is an identifier expected but i don't know what i need to put there

Tags: c#, identifier

What kind of identifier does the visual studio needs ? i just want to put from outside one int array with 2 different numbers between 0 and 66.

```
    public static void playerLocationChange(int[])
    {

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# identifier expected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225214/c-sharp-identifier-expected)

Comment: @Shaharyar Ironically, it would seem to be the exact reverse of the problem encountered in that question.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes you are right. Retracted the close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give the parameter a name. Otherwise, you have no way of referring to it from the function.

```
public static void playerLocationChange(int[] myIntArrayParam) 
                                        //Notice the name next to int[]
                                        //This is the parameter's name
{

}
```