# Novice trying to resolve Error CS1001 "Identifier Expected"

Tags: c#

I'm a complete novice trying to learn C# by making mods for a game called RimWorld. I obtained the source code of a mod that does something similar to what I'm trying to do, and have been tweaking it to see what I can make work. The following error has me stumped, as the bit of code in question is unmodified from the source code that I obtained from a working mod. I also don't know C# well enough to know what specifically Visual Studio is looking for, and copying solutions from similar questions hasn't yielded any results.

**Error: CS1001 - Identifier Expected - File: GetPawnThing.cs - Line 20**

```
using System;
using RimWorld;
using Verse;

namespace VehicleSpawnerName
{
    // Token: 0x02000002 RID: 2
    public class GetPawnThing : MoteThrown
    {
        // Token: 0x06000001 RID: 1 RVA: 0x00002050 File Offset: 0x00000250
        public override void Tick()
        {
            bool flag = base.Map == null;
            if (flag)
            {
                this.Destroy(0);
            }
            PawnKindDef Vehicle_Name = PawnKindDefOf.Vehicle_Name;
            PawnGenerationRequest pawnGenerationRequest;
            pawnGenerationRequest..ctor(Vehicle_Name, null, 2, -1, true, false, false, false, true, false, 20f, false, true, true, false, false, false, false, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            Pawn pawn = PawnGenerator.GeneratePawn(pawnGenerationRequest);
            pawn.ageTracker.AgeBiologicalTicks = 70000000L;
            GenSpawn.Spawn(pawn, base.Position, base.Map, 0);
            this.Destroy(0);
        }
    }
}
```

The line in question (according to the error report) is:

```
pawnGenerationRequest..ctor(Vehicle_Name, null, 2, -1, true, false, false, false, true, false, 20f, false, true, true, false, false, false, false, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `pawnGenerationRequest..ctor`? That's not source code, that's reverse-engineered code. Normally, that would have been `new PawnGenerationRequest(...)`

Comment: Decompiling a binary is not guaranteed to produce valid code.  That line is trying to call a constructor.

Comment: Thats good to know, I wouldn't know enough to tell the difference. Does that mean I can't expect this code to work at all?

Comment: You need to interpret what it is trying to do and rewrite it into correct code.  Do you know how to call an object constructor?

Comment: No, but I will go read some tutorials on how to go about it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I'll give you a hint.  `pawnGenerationRequest..ctor(....)` is the decompiler saying "call the `PawnGenerationRequest` constructor with these arguments".  If you can't get it, come back and we can help further.  This is a good learning exercise.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing your parameter types is your method.

Here is a link of a similar error. [c# identifier expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225214/c-sharp-identifier-expected)

Comment: Hi Branden, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please expand your answer a little, explain the reasoning and the approach you would take to solving the problem. Also please provide the actual solution instead of linking to the solution.